# Error "Unable to resolve module aws-amplify-react-native"

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

[image]

I try to synchron my app with aws amplify but this issue happened

my App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import RootNavigator from "./src/navigation/index";
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import config from "./src/aws-exports";
import { withAuthenticator } from "aws-amplify-react-native";



Amplify.configure(config);

 function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
     

       <RootNavigator />

         <StatusBar style="light" />
      
       </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

amplify version 10.5.1

how i solve this issue

Comment: You need to run npm or yarn install on those packages that are missing.

Comment: I installed it and updated also but this issue still there

Comment: Check your import references that they are pointing to the right location, also check your node_modules

Answer (score 0):

Can try steps below:

1. rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean && yarn install
2. cd ios && pod install
3. Open xCode from yourapp.xcworkspace file inside ios folder.
4. Select Clean Build Folder from xCode product menu.
5. Run your app directly from xCode product menu.

Also u can try:
import { withAuthenticator } from "./node_modules/aws-amplify-react-native";

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands in sequence:

```bash
npm install --legacy-peer-dep
npm install --force
npm audit fix
npm install aws-amplify-react-native --force
npm fund
npm audit fix --force
```

*(it worked for me)*